# Is the inverse Fourier transform of a radial function radial?

Tags: fourier-transform

Let $f: \Bbb{R}^d \to \Bbb{R}$ be a rapidly decreasing function in $\Bbb{R}^d$. Concerning Fourier transforms in $\Bbb{R}^d$, we define $\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{\Bbb{R}^d} f(x) e^{-2 \pi i \xi \cdot x}dx $, for $\xi \in \Bbb{R}^d$. And the inverse of $g(\xi)$ is $\int_{\Bbb{R}^d}g(\xi)e^{2 \pi i \xi \cdot x}d\xi$. A function $f: \Bbb{R}^d \to \Bbb{R}$ is said to be radial iff there is $F: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = F(|x|)$ for $x \in \Bbb{R}^d$. It is easy to prove that the transform of a radial function is radial. Does the same hold for inverse transforms?

Comment: the inverse transform of a function $f$ is the fourier trnasform of $x\mapsto f(-x)$

Comment: Yes, convert the cartesian n-dimensional Fourier Transform to n-spherical (?) coordinates and integrate over the angular variables.  You will be left with a transform that is a single integral in terms of the radial variable.  You can do the same for the inverse transform.  For n = 1, you will get the Fourier cosine transform.  For n = 2, you will get the zero order Hankel Transform.  For higher n, see  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3007081/441161