# Fourier transformation of Yukawa potential

Tags: fourier-transform

I'm trying to understand the first step of the fourier transformation of the Yukawa potential.

The Yukawa potential is a spherically symmetric potential in 3 dimensions defined as $V_Y(r) = e^{-\alpha*r}/r$ with $r=|\vec{r}|$ and $\alpha >0$

We obtain the Fourier transformation by using polar coordinates (the z-axis points along the direction of k⃗):

\begin{align*}
F(V_Y(r))&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}^{}\frac{e^{-\alpha*r}}{r}e^{-ik\vec{r}}d^3r
\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\alpha*r}}{r}e^{-ikr\cos(\theta)}r^2\sin(\theta)dr d\theta d\phi 
\end{align*}

The rest is just super painful integration.

I have a very basic understanding of how Fourier works and what it's expressing but I don't have too much of an idea how the Fourier space looks like. In this first step, I don't get how the integral becomes a spherical integral but at the same time we use polar coordinates to express $e^{-ik\vec{r}}$ as $e^{-ikr\cos(\theta)}$ and how it holds?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you move forward: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3007081/441161

Answer (score 1):

"The z axis points along the direction of k"

so k has a direction and is a vector... $\vec k$, and the angle between it and $\vec r$ is the polar angle $\theta$. The exponent will be
 $$
exp(-i\vec k \cdot\vec r)
$$
i.e a scalar product which is naturally $k \,r \cos \theta$.

Comment: but from where do I get the property, that k points along the z axis? is this a property of fourier?

Comment: It's something you stated in your question but aren't you are free to orient the coordinate frame so that z points in whatever direction is convenient.

Comment: That's something I don't know. But it still bugs me to treat r as a spherical and then as a polar variable if it makes sense?

Comment: $\vec r$ represents the position vector of points in space. For a spherically symmetric problem it is often convenient to use spherical polar coordinates $r, \theta, \phi$